# Cannot query over table without a filter that can be used for partition elimination

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a partitioned table and would love to use a MERGE statement, but for some reason doesn't work out.

```
MERGE `wr_live.p_email_event`  t
using `wr_live.email_event` s
on t.user_id=s.user_id and t.event=s.event and t.timestamp=s.timestamp
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (user_id,event,engagement_score,dest_email_domain,timestamp,tags,meta)
values (user_id,event,engagement_score,dest_email_domain,timestamp,tags,meta)
```

I get

> Cannot query over table 'wr_live.p_email_event' without a filter that
>   can be used for partition elimination.

What's the proper syntax? Also is there a way I can express shorter the insert stuff? without naming all columns?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> What's the proper syntax?

As you can see from error message  - your partitioned `wr_live.p_email_event` table was created with `require partition filter` set to true. This mean that any query over this table must have some filter on respective partitioned field

Assuming that `timestamp` IS that partitioned field - you can do something like below

```
MERGE `wr_live.p_email_event`  t
USING `wr_live.email_event` s
ON t.user_id=s.user_id AND t.event=s.event AND t.timestamp=s.timestamp
AND DATE(t.timestamp) > CURRENT_DATE()  -- this is the filter you should tune 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (user_id,event,engagement_score,dest_email_domain,timestamp,tags,meta)
VALUES (user_id,event,engagement_score,dest_email_domain,timestamp,tags,meta)
```

So you need to make below line such that it in reality does not filter out whatever you need to be involved

```
AND DATE(t.timestamp) <> CURRENT_DATE()  -- this is the filter you should tune
```

For example, I found, setting it to timestamp in future - in many cases addresses the issue, like

```
AND DATE(t.timestamp) > DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Of course, if your `wr_live.email_event` table also partitioned with `require partition filter` set to true - you need to add same filter for s.timestamp

> Also is there a way I can express shorter the insert stuff? without naming all columns?

BigQuery DML's INSERT requires `column names to be specified` - there is no way (at least that I am aware of) to avoid it using INSERT statement
Meantime, you can avoid this by using DDL's CREATE TABLE from the result of the query. This will not require listing the columns

For example, something like below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `wr_live.p_email_event`
PARTITION BY DATE(timestamp) AS
SELECT * FROM `wr_live.p_email_event` 
WHERE DATE(timestamp) <> DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM `wr_live.email_event` s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM `wr_live.p_email_event` t
  WHERE t.user_id=s.user_id AND t.event=s.event AND t.timestamp=s.timestamp
  AND DATE(t.timestamp) > DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
)
```

You might also want to include table options list via OPTIONS() - but looks like filter attribute is not supported yet  - so if you do have/need it  - above will "erase" this attribute :o(

Comment: Thanks for the reminder--I think it should work to use `require_partition_filter` with CREATE TABLE but we need to document it.

Comment: Great. Thank you @ElliottBrossard