# How to perform ETL on BigQuery avoiding duplications?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a product table of:
`id  createdOn UpdatedOn` and 76 more columns.

`createdOn UpdatedOn` are `TIMESTAMP`. 
`createdOn` is the partition field.

Each ETL loads records from storage to product table (append).

Once ETL finishes I have duplication in the product table.

Example:

```
id  createdOn,                    updatedOn,                stock, status
1   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676  10    5
3   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676  10     5
1   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676  10     5
3   2018-09-14 14:14:24.305676   2018-09-15 10:00:00.000000  7     5
```

I want to remove the duplicated `id`s. The record with the most recent `updatedOn` needs to stay, rest needs to be removed.

I acted according to the suggestion here: [Google BQ - how to upsert existing data in tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177241/google-bq-how-to-upsert-existing-data-in-tables)
This is my query:

```
   DELETE FROM `storage.prodcuts` AS d
   WHERE (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY createdOn, id ORDER BY updatedOn DESC)
           FROM `storage.prodcuts` AS d2
           WHERE d.id = d2.id ) > 1;
```

This doesn't work:

> Error: Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not
>   supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming
>   them into an efficient JOIN.

Also tried:

```
 delete FROM `storage.prodcuts` as p
  ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY createdOn, id  order by updatedOn DESC) as rn , id FROM `storage.prodcuts` ) as t
WHERE t.rn> 1 and p.id=t.id;
```

Gives:

> Syntax error: Unexpected "(" at [3:7]

I assume that BigQuery wants me to join between the `delete table` and the `row_number` table (though its the same one)? how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using the MERGE statement? It's part of the same DML documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I'm not sure this is doable. I have 76 columns. Each one of them can be updated. This is a nightmare to specify everything manually.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain two table, one that you have right now: everything in, have another table which is the cleanup version, you can MERGE from the 1st to 2nd table based on the `id` column only. This way the latest row will be in the second table, and with the MERGE statement it will be overwritten all the time.

You can now even [Schedule Queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) so your MERGE statements can be executed automatically every X times.

Comment: This instructions are written everywhere yet none of the places show actual example of how to do it with a table with dozes of columns. I am more than happy to adopt this method but from what I see such query will be a nightmare. say I have production_products and recent_products (which is the ETL table) . How do you suggest to merge recent_products (ETL) into production_products when having 76 columns. Should I specify 76 columns in the Insert and Update statement? :/

Comment: Please note that in SQL only SELECT * is something where you omit naming the columns, in all others INSERT/UPDATE/MERGE you need to name all the columns. See the answer here that applies to you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194105/cannot-query-over-table-without-a-filter-that-can-be-used-for-partition-eliminat

Comment: I'm using Apache Airflow for scheduling tasks. I need only statements where I can run as SQL. Do you see a way where I can make my delete work?

Comment: Write the select to a temp table. Use that in your DELETE. Self-referencing is not possible.

Comment: Can you explain why something like" MERGE dataset.products T USING dataset.products_etl S ON T.id= S.id"  cant be done ? Why I must specify the Insert and the Update? I want all columns to be update and if id doesn't exists then insert the whole row.

Comment: The SQL standard doesn't define MERGE like that.

Comment: and what about legacy SQL?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have rows with duplicate (id, updatedOn) pairs, or can resolve such duplicates in other ways, you can do something simple like below to achieve this:

```
DELETE FROM `storage.prodcuts` AS d
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `storage.prodcuts` p2 
              WHERE p2.id = d.id AND p2.updatedOn > d.updatedOn)
```

But from maintainability perspective, the Pentium10's solution of using two tables I think is way superior.

Comment: I can have duplicates.. note my example (id=1). Pentinum10 answer while interesting still force me to specify 76 columns in the update and in the insert. it's one thing mention them for insert but update it too much. I must do : update  set id=id,createdOn=createdOn..... that will take hours!

Comment: I honestly don't understand why there isn't "MERGE dataset.products T
USING dataset.products_etl S ON T.id= S.id"  Why I must specify everything? Simply insert id that doesn't exist and what exists update the whole row