# BigQuery doesn't recognize filter

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

BigQuery doesn't recognize filter over column timestamp and outputs this:

> **Cannot query over table 'xxxxxx' without a filter over column(s) 'timestamp' that can be used for partition elimination**

Query code that produced this message is:

```
SELECT project as name,
    DATE_TRUNC(timestamp, DAY) as day,
    COUNT (timestamp) as cnt
FROM `xxxxxx` 
WHERE (DATETIME(timestamp) BETWEEN DATETIME_ADD(DATETIME('2022-02-13 00:00:00 UTC'), INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
    AND DATETIME_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATETIME(), DAY), INTERVAL 1 SECOND))
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: It sounds like it didn't like the datetime conversion on the partition column:timestamp. Can you try leaving it by itself and convert the two datetime conditions to timestamp?

Comment: Tried, same error

Comment: You are actually right, but every datetime conversion should be replaced with timestamp

Answer (score 2):

Everything works if we switch every conversion to DATETIME and all DATETIME operations with TIMESTAMP format and TIMESTAMP type operations.

```
SELECT project as name,
    DATE_TRUNC(timestamp, DAY) as day,
    COUNT (timestamp) as cnt
FROM `xxxxxx` 
WHERE (timestamp BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP('2022-02-13 00:00:00 UTC'), INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
    AND TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), DAY), INTERVAL 1 SECOND))
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The table when being created  was created with require partition filter set to true.
Any query on this table should have a filter on the timestamp.

Refer :- [Cannot query over table without a filter that can be used for partition elimination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194105/cannot-query-over-table-without-a-filter-that-can-be-used-for-partition-eliminat)

Comment: Yes, but I have that filter, for some reason, bigquery doesn't recognize it